# How to validate currency value by Locale?

Tags: javascript, currency

We have a big web application, that has portals in different countries.
In these countries the money value is inserted differently.

Exists a solution which can validate the money value by locale?

Comment: It seems that my question was not understood, or I don't get the idea of the answers. My question is e.g.: User inputs in German portal: 1.234,98 so I want to validate if his insert was correct - in this example it was. But if the user inserts in the German portal the value: 1,234.98 then it is not correct, but in the US portal it would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented it now via an own function:

```
/*
* checks if a given money value is a correct one via locale language
* */
function isMoney(moneyValue) {
    var currentSelectedLanguage = $('#currentSelectedLanguage').val();
    switch (currentSelectedLanguage)
    {
        // checks for , as separator and . as decimal separator e.g.: 1,234,567,890.98 - also allows without , as separator e.g.: 1234567890.98
    case "en":
        return /(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test(moneyValue);
        break;

    // checks for . as separator and , as decimal separator e.g.: 1.234.567.890,98 - also allows without . as separator e.g.: 1234567890,98
    case "de":
    case "el":
    case "es":
    case "hr":
    case "ro":
    case "sl":
    case "sr":
        return /(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test(moneyValue);
        break;

    // checks for space as separator and , as decimal separator e.g.: 1 234 567 890,98, also allows without space as separator e.g.: 1234567890,98
    case "bg":
    case "cs":
    case "hu":
    case "pl":
    case "ru":
    case "sk":
    case "uk":
        return /(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}( [0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test(moneyValue);
        break;

    // checks for . as separator and , as decimal separator e.g.: 1.234.567.890,98 - also allows without . as separator e.g.: 1234567890,98
    default:
        return /(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]{1,2})?$/.test(moneyValue);
    }

}
```

Only downside is, that I've to extend it on my own if there is a new locale in our application

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend the http://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/ this would provide you the live currency conversion rates.

for the formatting purpose look into AccountingJs https://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: How is it possible to validate if the given value is a correct money value in the specific locale?

Comment: instead of validation you can just convert it into specific locale format, in that way you will always get correct value.

Comment: this is not possible, because there is a need for validation - the user needs to insert the correct value format, because it will then be converted via Java.

Comment: in that case, you can ask user only the price and then convert it to proper locale before sending it to java

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a dropdown next to the currency text box. so user can select the approperiate currency and can fill the value.

and in backend you need to get both value. entered value by user and the currecy selected.

based on location, you can change the selected currency by default.

Comment: The problem here is not the type of currency. It is the format the numerical value is entered. *"In these countries money value is inserted differently"*. Like writing `2.00` and `2,00` for different cultures.

Comment: use the regex to convert comma in to dot. and than use it for further processing.

or just replace using javascript -  str.replace(",", ".");

Comment: The point is, when you are dealing with multiple cultures over a huge web app, that kind of manual handling becomes unmanageable. You need to introduce a system to manage all the differences that come with different cultures. That *2.00* | *2,00* example is just the tip of the iceberg. Even in relatively small apps, that is very error prone and hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

*"We have a big web application, that has portals in different countries"*

I highly recommend setting up localization with [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). After setting it up correctly, all you have to do is change the `locale` of the user and all the locale dependent formatting (e.g currency, date, number, units, etc.) fixes itself.

If you want to use it just for currency, see their currency module: [Globalize Currency Module](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/currency/currency-formatter.md)

Comment: How is it possible to validate if the given value is a correct money value in the specific locale?